# Flutter: Illustrate List of Strings with a for-Loop doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I am really confused why does this only work without the braces around the for-Loop.

```
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              for (int i = 1; i < lst.length; i++)
                {
                  Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Text(lst[1]),
                    ),
                  )
                }
     ...
```

Comment: It is a different type of for statement that is used inside a collection. Same with the if statement. Neither of them can use {}, which means you can only have one statement that the operate on.

Comment: @GrahamD collection-`for` isn't technically a *statement*, nor does it contain statements.

Comment: @jamesdlin Semantics, apologies if I didn't use quite the correct terms. You could have just gone with your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are `for` *statements*:

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
  print(i);

var someList = <int>[];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  someList.add(i);
  print(i);
}
```

Statements typically end with semicolons, and curly braces can group statements together.  Statements *do* something.

You're not using a `for` *statement*; you're using Dart's "collection-`for`" syntax, which isn't actually a statement at all, nor does it contain any statements.  It's an *expression*, and its body must also be an expression (or rather, an "element").  Expressions evaluate to a *value* that is consumed by other expressions (and usually ultimately to a statement).

Since collection-`for` does not contain statements, braces are inappropriate (ditto for collection-`if`), and the extraneous braces instead will be treated as creating a `Set` literal.

I highly recommend reading the [Making Dart a Better Language for UI article](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c) which describes the motivation and design of collection-`for` and collection-`if`.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a matter of a syntax. Normal for loop in normal inline code works perfectly, but you use a special for operator in a dart collection. Same case with if statements.