# Is it possible to use a conditional statement as part of a CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl to control the number of options displayed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to have 2 sliding control options unless an integer variable is >0 in which case there will be 3 options

I'm using the following code block

```
                          child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                              children: {
                                0: Text('Option 1'),
                                1: Text('Option 2'),
                                2: Text('Option 3')

                              },
                              groupValue: _sliding,
                              onValueChanged: (newValue) {
                                   (...)
                              }),
```

I'd ideally like option 3 to only show up if `myInteger` is > 0, I tried the following code but it failed

```
                          child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                              children: {
                                0: Text('Option 1'),
                                1: Text('Option 2'),
                                if (myInteger > 0) {
                                  2: Text('Option 3')
                                }

                              },
                              groupValue: _sliding,
                              onValueChanged: (newValue) {
                                   (...)
                              }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [collection-`if`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators):

```dart
child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
    children: {
      0: Text('Option 1'),
      1: Text('Option 2'),
      if (myInteger > 0)
        2: Text('Option 3'),
    },
    groupValue: _sliding,
    onValueChanged: (newValue) {
         (...)
    }),
```

Your attempt didn't work because you added curly braces around the `if` body, but that's appropriate only for an `if` *statement* where the body can contain multiple statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126532/ for more details.