# How can I make Widget using iterator like 'for' in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I wanna make a number of widgets in the ListView by using iterator like for, like the example below,

```
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++ ){
 Text('hello world'),
}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work, showing me this error message.

```
The element type 'Set<Text>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

How can i fix this?

Thank you for concerning my question.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) Text('hello world'),`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126532/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ListView` you can use `List.generate`.

```
...
body: ListView(
  children: List.generate(
    10,
    (index) => ListTile(
      title: Text(index),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```

If you are traditional and wanna use `for` then go for it like this,

```
...
body: ListView(
  children:[ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    ListTile(title:Text("$i")),
  ]
),
...
```

If you have a very big list then consider using `ListView.builder`. Why? Because it renders only the widgets that are available on the screen which would be pretty fast to load. This is how to use it,

```
...
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("$index"),
    );
  }
),
...
```

Comment: I solved the problem with second manner, thank you very much!!!!